# Adding Picture to Panel Netbeans

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jlabel, imageicon

i'm using Netbeans and it's GUI designer tool,i want to add a picture to my background JPanel but i can't get into the code (It's grayed out and unchangeable)
so the normal "add image" won't work.
Also i tried to use a Label but that didn't work out either.

Or is simply my code to add it wrong?

```
BufferedImage biBackground= ImageIO.read(new File("path-to-file"));
JLabel biBackground= new JLabel(new ImageIcon(myPicture));
add(biBackground);
```

so i don't know where to put my code, because i cant add something to the "Initcomponents()" method

I'm sorry for the dumb question.

Comment: with correct [path-to-file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9864267/load-icon-image-exception/9866659#9866659) works (by @nIcE cOw)

Comment: but my problem is i dont know where to put the code because i cant get into "Initcomponents()" method

Comment: @MadProgrammer are you sure that your NIC is unique, because we have here own, and excelent person [MadProgrammer](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/swing/topusers), really not good idea in this case ....

Comment: milion times here "Don't to use generated code", otherwise follows Netbeans tutorial about Mattise, :-) search on Netbeans forum

Comment: @mKorbel sorry could not understand NIC???

Comment: okay, sorry, i thought it would be easier for a newbe with this ^^'

Comment: (asier for a newbe) - not this Framework is long time depreciates,

Comment: @MadProgrammer (sorry could not understand NIC???) - some really and unique identifier, for unambiguous identification

Comment: @MadProgrammer Mkorbel is asking why you're using my user name ?

Comment: You don't have to add content into the initComponent method, you can perform modifications after it. Adding a background image is normally done by extending a class from JPanel and overriding its paintComponent method and painting the image there

Comment: I was not aware of that,Because when i changed my name last time SO did not display any unique error or like that,now it is not allowing me to change, only after six days may be some policy..